# regex is not matching content in multiple line in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex expression is working when the content is in the same line. But it does not work if the same content is in multiple line. Please identify a mistake

Regex:

```
   <([^\s]+).*?id="opensource".*?>(.+?)<\/\1>
```

It works with content in same line:

```
  <article id="opensource">Cabby </article>
```

It does not works with content in different line:

```
 <article id="opensource">
  Cabby
 </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for the whitespace characters.

```regex
<([^\s]+).*?id="opensource".*?>(?:\s+)?(.+?)(?:\s+)?<\/\1>
```

Here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/OQH7A5/1

Comment: `(?:\s+)?` is better written `\s*` and `[^\s]+` `\S+`.

Comment: @Toto tru I knew that lol

Comment: Try with `<div>blah</div><tag></tag><article id="opensource">Cabby</article>`